# Find and replace phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have around 20k URLs using this pattern bellow and I am trying to replace and remove this
`fffd8ca225794d4c3c9f33a2ec321828`of these URLs using phpMyAdmin

This is just an example, all these strings are random

What it is
https://www.xxxx.com/file/0/fffd8ca225794d4c3c9f33a2ec321828/740000/740640/screenshots/1.jpg

What I need
https://www.xxxx.com/contents/sources/740000/740640/screenshots/1.jpg

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple UPDATE query with `REPLACE` function:

```
    UPDATE <your table name> 
    SET <your field name> = REPLACE(
        <your field name>, 
        'fffd8ca225794d4c3c9f33a2ec321828/', -- find this substring
        '' -- replace by empty string
    );
```

[Test MySQL REPLACE online](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/a78c954763f7dbfa4688ef2b092b8ba1/)

Since MySQL 8.0 you can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` function

```
UPDATE urls SET url = REGEXP_REPLACE(
  url, 
  'file/0/[a-z0-9]+/', 'contents/sources/
');
```

[MySQL REGEXP_REPLACE test](https://sqlize.online/sql/mysql80/e9a6fdef17f790a1eddd85e2a2b7e8ea/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I have 20k of these URLs with random strings in them.... I have updated my question